# Líenard-Weichert potential satisfies the Lorenz gauge

Tags: mathematical-physics, vector-fields, index-notation

It can be shown in 3-vector notation that the Líenard-Weichert potential satisfies the Lorenz gauge condition $\frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d}t}+\vec{\nabla}\vec{A}=0$; I am interested in showing this in covariant notation.
$$A^{\mu}=\frac{qU^{\mu}(\tau_0)}{U_{\nu}(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu}\to\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=0$$
Here, $\tau_0$ depends implicitly on $x$ as $(x-r(\tau_0))^2=0$. My attempt is as follows:
$$\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=\frac{q}{U_{\nu}(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu}\frac{A_\alpha(\tau_0)}{U_{\alpha}(\tau_0)}-\frac{\partial_{\mu}[U_{\nu}(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu]}{U_{\nu}(\tau_0)U^{\nu}(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu[x-r(\tau_0)]_\nu}$$
Firstly, I have no idea when the use of additional indices is required ($\alpha$ in this case), and secondly what does it even mean to write $\partial_{\mu}[U_{\nu}(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu]$ given that the indices differ?

Comment: Some thoughts after taking only a brief look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential): 1) They don't say that the original LW potential satisfies the Lorenz gauge. This happens after adding a curl free (but not divergence free) gauge field that does not change curl $A$. To explain this they link to [gauge freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory#Classical_gauge_theory). 2) Your index $\nu$ is summed over $0,1,2,3$ as usual. 3) If you can show Lorenz gauge in $3$-vector notation it is trivial ...

Comment: ... to write this in $\partial_\mu A^\mu$ notation (as usual).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested:
$$\partial_\mu U_\nu(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu=\partial_\mu U^{\alpha}(\tau_0)g_{\alpha\nu}[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu=\frac{\psi^\alpha(\tau_0)}{U^\alpha(\tau_0)}\delta^{\alpha\mu}g_{\alpha\nu}[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu=\frac{\psi^\mu(\tau_0)}{U^\mu(\tau_0)}[x-r(\tau_0)]_\mu$$
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu([x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha)
&=\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha+\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha\\
&=\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha+\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]^\delta g_{\alpha\delta} [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha\\
&=\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha+\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]^\delta [x-r(\tau_0)]_\delta\\
&=2\partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha\to \partial_\mu [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha=0 
\end{align}
Where in the final line we used that $[x-r(\tau_0)]^\alpha [x-r(\tau_0)]_\alpha=0$:
$$\partial_\mu A^\mu(x)=\frac{q}{U_\nu(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]^\nu}\frac{\psi^\mu(\tau_0)}{U^\mu(\tau_0)}-\frac{q}{U^\nu(\tau_0)[x-r(\tau_0)]_\nu}\frac{\psi^\mu(\tau_0)}{U^\mu(\tau_0)}=0$$

Edit: Forgot to mention that $\psi^\mu(\tau_0)$ denotes the 4-acceleration in order to avoid confusion with the potential $A^\mu(x)$